Applying for a visa on German PR expiring in 3 months
I hold a German PR that will expire 3 months from now. I would like to visit some countries since I have some free time at the moment, the countries can be either Albania, Turkey or the UK.
I checked first for Albania and according to the e-visa site, it is evident I require an e-visa because I hold a non-EU passport, and qualify for an e-visa since I hold a valid PR, according to the following statement:

Foreign citizens who have a valid, multiple-entry Schengen visa, which has been previously used in one of the Schengen states, or foreign citizens who have a valid permit of stay in one of the Schengen states.

My question is, am I still allowed to apply for e-visa and travel even though my travel document ie my German PR is expiring in 3 months (my passport still has a longer validity than my PR)? Or does my PR need to have some minimal validity in order for me to qualify for any kind of visas (or e-visas)?
